# 3D touch shortcut: load other URL

Tags: ios, swift

I have implemented three 3D touch actions, lets name them `app.touch1`, `app.touch2` and `app.touch3`.

This is the code in my `AppDelegate` file:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, performActionForShortcutItem shortcutItem: UIApplicationShortcutItem, completionHandler: (Bool) -> Void) {
    if(shortcutItem.type == "app.touch1"){
        MyVariables.url = "https://google.de/";
    } else if(shortcutItem.type == "app.touch2") {
        MyVariables.url = "https://yahoo.de/";
    } else if(shortcutItem.type == "app.touch3") {
        MyVariables.url = "https://bing.de/";
    }
}
```

This is my `MyVariables` class for now:

```
struct MyVariables {
    static var url = "https://test.de/"
}
```

This is the code of my `ViewController` class:

```
IBOutlet var containerView : UIView?
var webView: UIWebView?
var loadedURL: String?

override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
    return true
}

override func loadView() {
    super.loadView()

    self.webView = UIWebView()
    self.view = self.webView!
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    load()
}

func load() {
    let requestURL = NSURL(string: MyVariables.url)
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: requestURL!)
    self.webView!.loadRequest(request)
    loadedURL = MyVariables.url
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

However, it always loads the default url (`https://test.de/`), even if the app was closed before. I tried events like `viewDidAppear` and `viewWillAppear` also, but this did not work.

I think this is very simple for an iOS developer - I tried to start with iOS and have this problem :-(

Comment: Already checked in your AppDelegate with print(shortcutItem.type) which block gets executed?

Comment: @derdida: Yes, it is the correct block.

Comment: Did you manage to get this working?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that your ViewController class is being loaded before the App Delegate has finished launching (because it's the root view controller), so the code that sets the URL hasn't been called at the point that you make the request.

What you need to do is either make performActionForShortcutItem start the request on the ViewController, or find another way to trigger that code.

Answer (score 2):

So its look like this is only a problem with your struct?

I would try to set a global variable in your AppDelegate, and then use it in your ViewController.

For example:

Create an url variable in your **AppDelegate**.

In your **ViewController** use:

```
func load() {
    let delegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
    let requestURL = NSURL(string: delegate.url)
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: requestURL!)
    self.webView!.loadRequest(request)
    loadedURL = MyVariables.url
}
```

Try it out, it should work. Another idea would be to store it as Singleton, check this out here:

https://github.com/hpique/SwiftSingleton

Or (it depends on your data you want to archive) -> store it as NSUserDefaults()

Comment: Thats not a good error description. What is not working? And are there any error messages?

Comment: No. It just do not load the correct page. Same problem as before.

Comment: And what have you tried? To use your delegate variables here? Post more code, try to debug that code (so make some "print" statements to check what happened)

Answer (score 0):

We have something almost identical working in our app, you can check [the commit that created it](https://github.com/exoplatform/exo-ios/commit/cba1a0411bf7ac086d4891656520464b0d677f4d).

The main parts are:

1) In the AppDelegate, detect which shortcut item was selected

- You are already doing that.

2) Create and open a new ViewController with the correct parameter

Cf [our function](https://github.com/exoplatform/exo-ios/commit/cba1a0411bf7ac086d4891656520464b0d677f4d#diff-e8e7cde7d9ee7c5128830b75e9a900f6R111) `quickActionOpenHomePageForURL`

```
func quickActionOpenHomePageForURL (stringURL:String) {
        if (navigationVC != nil) {
            if (navigationVC?.viewControllers.count > 0) {
                navigationVC?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(false)
                let homepage = navigationVC?.viewControllers.last?.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("HomePageViewController")
                (homepage as! HomePageViewController).serverURL  =  stringURL
                navigationVC?.pushViewController(homepage! as UIViewController, animated: false)
            }
        }        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As per [IanW](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4146451/ianw) said

> The problem is that your ViewController class is being loaded before
>   the App Delegate has finished launching (because it's the root view
>   controller), so the code that sets the URL hasn't been called at the
>   point that you make the request.
>
> What you need to do is either make performActionForShortcutItem start
>   the request on the ViewController, or find another way to trigger that
>   code.

This `performActionForShortcutItem` is executing first then after `UIAppDelegate` class will be executed!

There are many ways to change the URL
1) Using the `NSNotificationCenter`
2) Take the public variable and change the URL
3) Take the Bool and then you can check that in your `ViewController` and base on that you can assign the 'URL'

**Example:**

First, take one public variable in `UIAppDelegate` class like below:

```
public var urlToLoad: String?
```

Secondly, assign the URL to load once you get the below method called!

```
func application(application: UIApplication, performActionForShortcutItem shortcutItem: UIApplicationShortcutItem, completionHandler: (Bool) -> Void) {
    if(shortcutItem.type == "app.touch1"){
        urlToLoad = "https://google.de/";
    } else if(shortcutItem.type == "app.touch2") {
        urlToLoad = "https://yahoo.de/";
    } else if(shortcutItem.type == "app.touch3") {
        urlToLoad = "https://bing.de/";
    }
}
```

That's it, now you can access this variable in any of the `UIViewController` Class

```
func load() {
    let requestURL = NSURL(string: MyVariables.url)
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: requestURL!)
    self.webView!.loadRequest(request)
    loadedURL = urlToLoad
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately your example does not work. As IanW stated - "The problem is that your ViewController class is being loaded before the App Delegate has finished launching" - The `ViewController` is loading BEFORE the `AppDelegate`. Therefore, it seems as if the `AppDelegate` needs to call a function within the `ViewController` once it's done it's part. Your example assumes that `AppDelegate` is called first, and then `ViewController`, hence making `urlToLoad` a value of `nil`.